# Return the int value for a specific column in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In my data frame DF I have a column called 'A' and its values are integer values. However when I want to retrieve the value of A for a specific row using

```
DF[DF.someCondition=condition].A
```

it returns an object of shape (1,) that is not int because int does not have a shape. I want int because I want to use this value as an index entry to another numpy array. How can I retrieve the value of A so that it's an int value?

Comment: Try this: `DF.loc[DF.someCondition=condition, 'A']`

Comment: This is wrong. I don't want a location. I want the value of A

Comment: did you try it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a condition of the form

```
DF.someCondition = condition
```

may be True more than once. That is why

```
DF[DF.someCondition=condition].A
```

returns an object of shape `(1,)` rather than a scalar value.
If you are certain that the condition is True only once, then you can extract the scalar value using [`item`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html)

```
DF[DF.someCondition=condition].A.item()
```

However, as [MaxU suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641511/return-the-int-value-for-a-specific-column-in-a-pandas-data-frame/40641642#comment68515005_40641511), it is better to use `.loc` to avoid chained-indexing:

```
DF.loc[DF.someCondition=condition, 'A'].item()
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2), columns=list('AB'))
df[df['B']==3].A
# 1    2
# Name: A, dtype: int64

df.loc[df['B']==3, 'A'].item()
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

Using `iter` as suggested by unutbu definitely gets the job done; however it must be noted that the function has been deprecated as of 2018.

Using the `iter` function as suggested in unutbu's answer will result in a warning that looks as below:

> FutureWarning: `item` has been deprecated and will be removed in a
>   future version

As is evident from the warning, this functionality will soon removed. This information can also be found in the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d1accd032b648c9affd6dce1f81feb9c99422483/pandas/core/base.py#L724-L740) code.

[image: Source Screenshot]

As posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57390363/pandas-item-has-been-deprecated) following is the workaround using `iter` with `next` if the first matched value is required:

```
x = df.loc[df['B']==3, 'A'].item()
next(iter(x), 'no match')
```

The advantage is that if no value is matched the default value can be returned.

In case you are further interested, this issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20419) and [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4300) .