# Pandas: `item` has been deprecated

Tags: python, pandas

So far I used this line of code here:

```
max_total_gross = event_data["max_total_gross"].loc[event_data["event_id"] == event_id].item()
```

Since I updated Pandas I receive the future warning:

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:12:
>   FutureWarning: `item` has been deprecated and will be removed in a
>   future version   if sys.path[0] == '':

I tried to fix it that way, but it's not the same outcome:

```
event_data.loc[event_data.event_id == event_id, 'max_total_gross']
```

I expected a single integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need first matched value use `iter` with `next`, advantage is if no value is matched is returned default value:

```
s = event_data.loc[event_data.event_id == event_id, 'max_total_gross']

out = next(iter(s), 'no match')
print (out)
```

Comment: Is next/iter also the right way to deal with that data if I need it for further calculations (not to just print it)? At a later point in my code, I do `event_orders["y"] = event_orders["total_gross_cumsum"] / (max_total_gross * 100)`. I expected more of a way like s[0] (doesn't work) to access that value. next/iter would have never come to my mind.

Comment: I was experimenting a bit more and I found this here working as well: `max_total_gross = event_data.loc[
        event_data["event_id"] == event_id, "max_total_gross"
    ].values[0]` What do you think is better to use?

Comment: @JoeyCoder - Your solution is good, if always matchad at least one value. If not, if failed. So it depends of data, I prefer more general solution...

Answer (score 13):

You could also just use [.iloc[0]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html), but keep in mind that it will raise an `IndexError` if there is not at least one item in the series you're calling it on.

```
s = event_data.loc[event_data.event_id == event_id, 'max_total_gross']
s.iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 7):

The method `item()` is still useful if you want to assert that the Series has length exactly 1, and also get that single value at the same time. I recommend replacing:

```
result = ser.item()
```

with:

```
result = ser.values.item()
```

which should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It has been undeprecated again in pandas 1.0 for exactly this use case:

> Series.item() and Index.item() have been *undeprecated* (GH29250)

from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#deprecations. See also discussion in the issue [GH29250](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29250).

So consider updating or ignoring or silencing the warning instead.